# results in stopped working when running reverse string program

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, reverse

> I wrote the function to reverse a string in c++ but it results in "stopped working".

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

string reverse(string s1)
{
    string s2;
    for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++)s2[i]=s1[s1.length()-i-1];
    return s2;
}

int main()
{
    string s1,s2;

    cin>>s1;
    s2=reverse(s1);
    cout<<s2;

}
```

> What can be the problem?

Comment: You aren't returning anything from `int main()`. `main()` is a function like any other and it has a return value, so `return 0` or whatever value is appropriate. That might fix your problem.

Comment: What is the length of the result string in the reverse() function?

Comment: @Jonathon `return 0` in main is implied, you don't have to provide it.

Comment: @JonathonOgden `main` is an exception where you dont have to return something, in that case it will `return 0`.

Comment: Btw, the header is `<string>`, `<string.h>` is a C header you should include as `<cstring>` if you ever need it (you do not for this code).

Comment: Pre assign string s2=s1; in your reverse()

Comment: @Barry yes I'm aware, I was under no illusion that was the main issue. That said, better to be explicit than to imply, especially as it's not clear what tools and/or environment this is being compiled in.

Comment: @AjayPandya thanks it works now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you accessing string s2 outside its boundaries. You are only allowed to access characters with [] that already exist; attempting to write outside the string causes undefined behaviour.

One possible solution is to pre-allocate s2:

```
string s2 = s1;
```

Another option is to count down over s1, and then simply add new characters to the end of s2.

Answer (score 2):

The function declaration has a drawback. First of all in fact it does not reverse a string. It makes a copy of a string in the reverse order.

Also it is more efficient to declare the parameter as constant reference.

For example

```
std::string reverse_copy( const std::string &s );
```

Within the function you are using the subscript operator applied to an ampty string

```
string s2; // the string is empty
for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++)s2[i]=s1[s1.length()-i-1];
                              ^^^^^
```

that results in undefined behaviour.

Also instead of the index of type `int` it is better to use an index of type `std::string::size_type`.

The function can be written without any explicit loop. For example

```
std::string reverse_copy( const std::string &s );
{
    return std::string( s.rbegin(), s.rend() );
}
```

If you want to use a loop then the function can look like

```
std::string reverse_copy( const std::string &s );
{
    std::string t;
    t.reserve( s.size() );

    for ( auto i = s.size(); i != 0; --i ) t.push_back( s[i-1] );

    return t;
}
```

Instead of the statement

```
t.push_back( s[i-1] );
```

you can write also

```
t += s[i-1];
```

For example

```
std::string reverse_copy( const std::string &s );
{
    std::string t;
    t.reserve( s.size() );

    for ( auto i = s.size(); i != 0; --i ) t += s[i-1];

    return t;
}
```

Comment: `return std::string( s.rbegin(), s.rend() );` is particularly elegant. Plus one.

Answer (score 1):

you can't index into a string when it's not been formed as yet.

Correct your code as follows and append to `s2` rather than index into it

```
string reverse(string s1)
{
    string s2;
    for (int i = 0; i<s1.length(); i++)
        s2 += s1[s1.length() - i - 1];

    return s2;
}
```

Comment: yapp now i understand the reasoning!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using standard algorithms, the problem is almost always that you're not using standard algorithms.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

std::string reverse(const std::string& s)
{
    std::string result;
    result.reserve(s.size());
    std::copy(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), std::back_inserter(result));
    return result;
}
int main()
{
    auto s = std::string("Hello, World");
    auto s2 = reverse(s);

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << s2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

expected result:

```
Hello, World
dlroW ,olleH
```

Answer (score 0):

`s2` does not have a well-defined length: you are assuming it has at least the same length as `s1`. Specifically, the behaviour of `s2[i]` is *undefined*.

Consider the C++ standard library-based solution

```
std::string s2(s1);
std::reverse(s2.begin(), s2.end());
```

Where conceptually, I'm considering the string as a *container* of `char`s.Using standard functions means that someone viewing your code knows *exactly* what you're doing.